# Editing MySQL recode using a HTML form

Tags: php, mysql

Im working on a small PHP project for learning purpose. i want to retrieve saved data from a MySQL data base and let the user edit it using a HTML form. im able to retrieve the data and  display in the text boxes. problem is when the form is submitted data is not updating. here is the code i got so far. file is made to update it self. if anyone can tell me where did i go wrong it will be most appreciated. thank you.

```
<?php

include ("header.php");
include ("../db.php");

$catname = $_POST['catname'];
$catdisc = $_POST['catdisc'];

$id = $_GET['id'];
        if (isset($id))
        {
$query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE catid='$id'";
$result= mysql_query($query) or die ('Mysql Error');

}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$cname = $row['catname'];
$cdisc = $row['catdisc'];
}

$result= "UPDATE categories SET catname='$catname', catdisc='$catdisc' WHERE catid='$id'"
or die ('Error Updating'); 

?>

<h1>Edit Categories</h1>

<form method="post" action="edit_cat.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">
Category Name: <input type="text" name="catname" value="<?php echo $cname;?>"><br/>
Category Discription: <TEXTAREA NAME="catdisc"ROWS="3" COLS="25"><?php echo $cdisc;?></TEXTAREA><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Update Category"/>
</form>

<?php
include ("footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: I can't see where you execute the update query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result= mysql_query("UPDATE categories SET catname='$catname', catdisc='$catdisc' WHERE catid='$id'") or die ('Error Updating');
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't executing the UPDATE-statement ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you define the SQL update command in a string, but, uh, you don't submit it to the database. There's a

$result= mysql_query($query) or die ('Mysql Error');

-like row missing.

Have in mind: (just another thing) that code is highly insecure - as it is.

You *MUST* check users POST input data, that finds is way into your SQL statements. Unless you do that, everyone online can have full database user privileged arbitrary access. Google: "SQL Injection".

Rob

PS Uh that took 5 minutes...

Comment: can you please explain what u meant by "-like row missing". could you give a example? thanks

Comment: a row like the one above. things are fixed here I think :)

Answer (score 0):

Some changes to your example code, hope this helps you

```
<?php
include ("header.php");
include ("../db.php");

//Getting Data
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
if (isset($id)){
    $query = "SELECT `categories`.`catid` AS catid,
                     `categories`.`catname` AS catname,
                     `categories`.`catdisc` AS catdesc
              FROM categories 
              WHERE catid='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."'
              LIMIT 1";
    $result= mysql_query($query) or die ('Mysql Error');
}
//Looping through the result, tho we know only 1 result will return
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>=1){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $cat['id'] = $row['catid'];
    $cat['name'] = $row['catname'];
    $cat['description'] = $row['catdesc'];
}
}else{
    $notice = 'No results found matching id:'.htmlentities($id);
}

//Updating Content

//Checking if form has been submitted with some basic checks
if(
isset($_POST['catid']) && is_numeric($_POST['catid'])==TRUE 
&& isset($_POST['catname']) && $_POST['catname']!="" 
&& isset($_POST['catdesc']) && $_POST['catdesc']!=""){


$cat['id'] = (int)$_POST['catid'];
$cat['name'] = (string)$_POST['catname'];
$cat['description'] = (string)$_POST['catdesc'];

//Create the query
$query="UPDATE categories 
            SET catname='".mysql_real_escape_string($cat['name'])."', catdisc='".mysql_real_escape_string($cat['description'])."' 
            WHERE catid='".mysql_real_escape_string($cat['id'])."'";
//Execute the update
mysql_query($query) or die ('Error Updating');
}
?>

<h1>Edit Categories</h1>

<form method="post" action="">
<?php echo (isset($notice))?$notice:'';?>
<input type="hidden" name="catid" value="<?php echo htmlentities($id);?>">
Category Name: <input type="text" name="catname" value="<?php echo $cat['name'];?>"><br/>
Category Discription: <TEXTAREA NAME="catdisc" ROWS="3" COLS="25"><?php echo $cat['description'];?></TEXTAREA><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Update Category"/>
</form>
```

**edit** whoops i forgot to add the id to the form field