# How to protect this form from SQL injections

Tags: php, mysql, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Editing MySQL recode using a HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705191/editing-mysql-recode-using-a-html-form)

Like to know how to validate the inputs of this submit form. by validate i meant keep it safe from SQL injections. Any help will be really appreciated. thank you.

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(ausername)){
header("location:main_login.php");
}
include ("header.php");
include ("../db.php");

$catname = $_POST['catname'];
$catdisc = $_POST['catdisc'];

$id = $_GET['id'];
        if (isset($id))
        {
$query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE catid='$id'";
$result= mysql_query($query) or die ('Mysql Error');

}
//Get category name and discription
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$cname = $row['catname'];
$cdisc = $row['catdisc'];
}
?>

<?php

$result= mysql_query ("UPDATE categories SET catname='$catname', catdisc='$catdisc' WHERE catid='$id'")
or die ('Error Updating'); 

?>

<h1>Edit Categories</h1>

<form method="post" action="../admin/edit_cat.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">
Category Name: <input type="text" name="catname" value="<?php echo $cname;?>"><br/>
Category Discription: <TEXTAREA NAME="catdisc"ROWS="3" COLS="25"><?php echo $cdisc;?></TEXTAREA><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Update Category"/>
</form>

<?php
include ("footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: i previously fixed & answered this piece of code:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705191/editing-mysql-recode-using-a-html-form/6705379#6705379 -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

strings (have to be in single/double quotes in query!) -> [mysql_real_escape_string();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

integers (could be without quotes) -> [intval();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

```
$catname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['catname']);
$catdisc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['catdisc']);
$id = intval($_GET['id']);

$result= mysql_query ("UPDATE categories SET catname='$catname', catdisc='$catdisc' WHERE catid=$id")
```

Answer (score 2):

Add mysql_real_escape_string calls for all your query variables, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: this won't help in case he wouldn't close variable into quotes ;)

Comment: yes I know ;) That was just warning for you/later readers.

Answer (score 2):

See 'Avoidance Techniques' from the [PHP SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) docs.

Comment: +1 I was not aware of that chapter in the PHP manual. It even has a cartoon!

Answer (score 0):

Use a database library the uses placeholders. Better API, and it takes care of SQL injection for free.

For example, see prepare and execute in [MDB2](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use prepared statements whenever handling values that users can change: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

They make SQL injection impossible.